# Xamarin forms collection view ItemsUpdatingScrollMode for UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-forms-4

I'm using xamarin forms 4.4. Using `ItemsUpdatingScreollMode="KeepLastItemInView"` does not work on UWP as UWP does not support it yet. Is there any workaround useful while they release the newest version?

Ref. collection view progress: https://gist.github.com/hartez/7d0edd4182dbc7de65cebc6c67f72e14

Comment: Based on my test and CollectionView official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction, this feaure does not support on Xamarin.forms uwp, you could post your new feature on GitHub. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue created on Xamarin Forms: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9127